# Next js Button reload site and new fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js, fetch

I want to create a refresh Button. Reloading the page already works, but unfortunately the data is not re-fetched. Does anyone of you have an idea?

The code from the update button is:

```
    const { reload, query } = useRouter();

                    <Button
                        onClick={() => {
                            reload();
                        }}
                    >
                        Refresh
                    </Button>
```

The code from the fetch is:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000//${nr}`);
        const extractedData = data.data;
        setData(extractedData);

        if (extractedData) {
            const unixTimestamp = data.data.unixtime;
            const millisecons = unixTimestamp * 1000;
            const dateObj = new Date(millisecons);
            const humanDateformat = dateObj.toLocaleString();
            setunixTime(humanDateformat);
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: Can you show the full code for that component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you might want to recall the query and not refresh the page. You can assign the fetch call to a function and call the function on click.  This would look something like the following:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Page = () => {
  const nr = '/api/route/path';
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000//${nr}`);
      setData(data.data);
      console.log(data.data);
    } catch(e) {
     console.log(e);
    }
  }
  
  useEffect(() => { fetchData() }, []); //fetch data on page load
 
  return <Button disabled={loading} onClick={fetchData}>Refresh</Button>;
}
```